# Centre align H1 tag with image to the left and right of it

Tags: html, css, image

I am trying to find a way of center aligning a block containing an image to the left and right of a `H1` tag. The images need to wrap the `h1` tag. The `H1` tag needs to be able to grow with the size of title:

```html
<div class=titlewrap">
    <img src="/images/hl.png" class="dl">
        <h1 class="title">Gallery</h1>
    <img src="/images/hr.png" class="dr">    
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
<style>
.titlewrap .dl, .titlewrap .dr{
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.titlewrap .title{
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

If this is part of the UI (not the content) - pad the left of the H1 and use a CSS background image, then do the same with the wrapper (but pad the right end). Use `background-position` to align the image left or right.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was:

HTML markup:

```
<h1>
    <img src="img1.png" alt="back">
    This is the H1 text
    <img src="img2.png alt="logo">
</h1>
```

CSS Markup:

```
h1 {
    position: relative;
}

img[alt="back"] {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px /* Distance from the left side of the 
                  page where you want the image*/
}

img[alt="logo"] {
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px /* Distance from the right side of the
                   page where you want the image*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.titlewrap { float: left; left: 50%; position: relative}
.titlewrap > * {float:left; left: -50%}​
```